# How to use ManyToManyField in Django serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, active-model-serializers

I have created one model where I am using ManyToMany for one field:

```
class Hospitals(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

class HealthProduct(models.Model):
    hospital_list = models.ManyToManyField(Hospitals)
    ..
    ..
```

serializer

```
hospital_field = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id', queryset=Hospitals.objects.all(), many=True)

class HealthProductSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hospital_list = hospital_field

    class Meta:
        model = HealthProduct
        exclude = ("created_at", "updated_at")
```

Here I am passing a list of Hospital_object id to my serializer

```
{
    "hospital_list": [1, 2],
    ..    
}
```

and when I saved serializer data getting a response

```
{
    "hospital_list": [
        1,
        2
    ]
    ...
}
```

but I want to get saved response either like:

```
{
    "hospital_list": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Apollo Bangalore Cradle Ltd."
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Greenview Healthcare Pvt. Ltd."
            }
    ]
    ...
}
```

or

```
{
    "hospital_list": [
            "Apollo Bangalore Cradle Ltd.",
            "Greenview Healthcare Pvt. Ltd."
    ]
    ...
}
```

when I used:

```
hospital_list = HospitalSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
```

then I got a desire response for a saved object, that I mentioned in the first response.

How should I use the ManyToMany field in my serializer, to save and a get response in desire format?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    class HospitalsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Hospitals
            fields = '__all__'
    
    class HealthProductSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        hospital_list = HospitalsSerializer(many=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = HealthProduct
            exclude = ("created_at", "updated_at")
```

Basically the nested objects need to be serialized by their own serializer

Comment: One thing to note is, if you use `OneToOneField`, `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField` under the hood it uses `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` so the result you get deals with `primary key`. If you want to override that, you can explicitly mention the name of `serializer` as shown.